# Meteor Android app built on linux does not connect to remote server

Tags: android, linux, meteor

I am relatively new to android+meteor+linux development and recently am facing very stange issue which I can not locate which of the 3 above is connected to.

So I have a simple setup where I have 3 EC2 instances on amazon. 1 as a build server(based on parameters it updates one of the web servers), 1 as a development web server and 1 as a release web server. Development and release instances are identical except of the version of the content they hold.

The mobile app itself is built with 2 different machines. Mac for iOS and Linux for Android. Up until recently everything was working as supposed to until a few weeks ago I noticed that Android app does not connect to the remote server anymore. First Meteor status says that it is connecting after which it just switches to waiting.

I realize that the problem can be in many places that is why have tested everything separately until found out that Android app built on Linux and pointing to the development web server particulary does not connect. If I change something in this scenario for example build Android app on Mac or build Android app pointing to release server everything works. I understand that we can just build Android app on Mac as well but it makes me very uneasy that something just stops working out of blue.

**So far I know the following:**

- building server works as supposed to
- development web server is working as well(it is accessible through
  the web and iOS apps as well as Android app build on Mac machine)
- it is not a recent bug(reverting to previous versions does not work)

**For the reference:**

- I have all of the following set up in the project to the correct EC2
  instance:

  - process.env.ROOT_URL
  - process.env.MOBILE_ROOT_URL
  - process.env.MOBILE_DDP_URL
  - process.env.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL
  - process.env.ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX
- Neither meteor run nor meteor build seem to produce a working build
  on the device.
- The following cmd are used:

  - meteor build ~/[build folder name] --server=[link to EC2 instance
  - meteor run android-device --mobile-server [link to EC2 instance]

**Versions:**

- Meteor 1.4.2.3
- Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit(all are the same)
- Phone Samsung Galaxy s6 edge Android 7.0

Would appreciate any input if anyone has any idea what that behaviour could be caused by.